# paper.js using JS directly - how to use .getDistance function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, paperjs

I am implementing a paper.js script which was written inline using the paperscript type script element. It's been loaded by require.js now and it works fine, and I install it to the window object, making it globally accessible. Everything seems to work, only the functions like .getDistance() cannot be used anymore. How can I use them anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say what goes wrong without seeing some actual code. Could you create a simplified test-case that illustrates your issue?

Comment: Hi Jürg, it is about using JS directly like documented on your tutorial at http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly - I am doing the exact same thing as described under "Making the scope global", and I can access all paper.* classes and objects without the paper object but I still cannot use the methods on Point and Size, like .getDistance for example.

BTW nice to hear from you, I remember we once met in Zurich at some party in Güterbahnhof. It's a shame they are taking it down now!

Comment: Hi Alberto. That sounds strange! Could you put an example online for me to see the problem? This works at my end. And nice to hear we met IRL. Hard to say if I remember or not : )

Comment: Well this is the require.js module I've written: http://hastebin.com/rufexobeni.js - the problem lies on line #107 where .getDistance() gets called and an error occurs: Uncaught TypeError: Object NaN has no method 'getDistance'